# Regex - Delete chars between <!-- and -->

Tags: regex, unix, regex-negation

Earlier I tried some regex to trim strings between `<!-- and -->` (included these tags as well), but no success.

Could you give me some informations about the problem?

Comment: @Johnsyweb That's just plain wrong. Comments in HTML cannot contain another comment, so you don't go into problems with ambiguous markup - comment is just text ended with "-->" sequence (sequence in any place in comment will end it, you can't escape it)

Comment: @MBO: while in a comment, "-->" is unambiguously the end of a comment. However, "<!--" is not necessarily the start of a comment. This will probably lead to an exploitable surface. e.g. something which might strip events attribute could easily be stymied if this filtering were done afterwards: `<a href="<!--">-->" onmouseover="alert('uh oh')">Ooh! Move over me!</a>`. Even using regular expressions to parse *comments* is likely to be a bad idea.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Good point, I haven't considered start of comment inside tags... So it's still hard problem.

Comment: @MBO: at least `<xmp>` was abolished.

Answer (score 2):

Regex to match *HTML comments*:

```
/<!--.*?-->/s
```

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/qZ4uP9

Comment: I took the liberty to add the `s` modifier: by default `.` does not match line break chars in most regex implementations (with `s` it does).

Comment: @BartKiers: thanx, appreciated

Answer (score 2):

To match a comment in text that looks like the rule for XML comments (and very close to the HTML comments rule) you want something like this:

```
<!--.*?-->
```

Assuming that your language's RE engine supports non-greedy quantifiers. Removal requires repeatedly matching that across the whole input text and substituting for the empty string; the syntax for that depends on the language in question.

Without non-greedy quantifiers, things get more complex (NB, this is slightly off for HTML comments but you really don't want to learn the details of the difference):

```
<!--([^-]|-[^-])*-->
```

Be aware that `--` is not something you should encounter in an XML comment unless it is followed by a `>`; this is part of the nature of XML comments…